# How do I fix "premature eof" verifying tor with gpg?

Tags: gnupg, tor

I am trying to verify the latest Tor bundle (`tor-browser-linux32-9.0a4_en-US.tar.xz` is the package downloaded).

No success. Running Ubuntu 16.04, I issued the command:

```
gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x4E2C6E8793298290
```

It returns this:

```
gpg: requesting key 93298290 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: premature eof while reading hashed signature data
gpg: key 93298290: no valid user IDs
gpg: this may be caused by a missing self-signature
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:           w/o user IDs: 1
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

I have installed Tor versions many times without a problem. What is wrong?